# Why use an ampersand character (&) in PyQt Strings for GUI elements?

Tags: python, string, button, pyqt, label

I've read several tutorials for PyQt and they use an ampersand character (&) in Strings which are used to label buttons. For example:

```
self.submitButton = QPushButton("&Submit")
```

I searched for some explanation, but one problem is, that common search engines think they're so smart and ignore the & character, which is annoying. When I add quotes around it, it only makes me find less results and none, which explains anything about strange '&' characters.

- Is it something very basic and that's why no one is explaining it?
- Or is it PyQt specific?
- And why would I add an unnecessary character like that?
- Doesn't it only clutter the String unnecessarily?
- What kind of effect does it have on the handling of that String?

I also tried in the python console:

```
a = "&abc"
b = "abc"
a == b
```

which returns false.
Then I tried giving it as an argument to the print function:

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

which simple prints:

```
&abc
abc
```

So I still don't know what to make of this.

Comment: In wxPython:  The & character creates an accelerator key. The character that follows the & is underlined. This way the menu is accessible via the Alt+F shortcut. Maybe it is same in pyqt. http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/

Comment: yes @ρss that is same in PyQT

Comment: I see. I am so used to have accelerators displayed, that I didn't even notice them. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): (not related to python itself, but the concept is the same)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control interprets an
>   ampersand character (&) in the control's Text property to be an access
>   key prefix character.
>
> If the UseMnemonic property is set to true and a mnemonic character (a
>   character preceded by the ampersand) is defined in the Text property
>   of the Label, pressing ALT+ the mnemonic character sets the focus to
>   the control that follows the Label in the tab order. You can use this
>   property to provide proper keyboard navigation to the controls on your
>   form.

And from [pyqt.sourceforge.net](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html):

> A QLabel is often used as a label for an interactive widget. For this
>   use QLabel provides a useful mechanism for adding an mnemonic (see
>   QKeySequence) that will set the keyboard focus to the other widget.

E.g.:

```
QLineEdit* phoneEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
QLabel* phoneLabel = new QLabel("&Phone:", this);
phoneLabel->setBuddy(phoneEdit);
```